# magento2 on kubernetes

Tags: magento2.3, docker, devops

I am trying to deploy magento on Kubernetes, I am using php-fpm as a base image with nginx, the magento files are available locally on Docker, but when I move it to Kubernetes i do not`enter code here` see anything in the PVC,

FROM php:8.2.12-fpm@sha256:2aa938b6d62f7415e9c84d867d9ceed18ef8ec3cf3944d389e088c93f9678a84 as base
ENV MAGENTO_PUBLIC_KEY ""
ENV MAGENTO_PRIVATE_KEY ""
ENV MAGENTO_VERSION 2.4.6-p3
ENV COMPOSER_HOME=/tmp/composer

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg 
nginx 
netcat-openbsd 
libicu-dev 
libfreetype6-dev 
libjpeg-dev 
libpng-dev 
libsodium-dev 
libxml2-dev 
libxslt-dev 
libzip-dev 
rsync 
supervisor 
unzip 
cron 
default-mysql-client 
git 
gnupg 
gzip 
libbz2-dev 
libfreetype6-dev 
libicu-dev 
libjpeg62-turbo-dev 
libmagickwand-dev 
libmcrypt-dev 
libonig-dev 
libpng-dev 
libsodium-dev 
libssh2-1-dev 
libwebp-dev 
libxslt1-dev 
libzip-dev 
lsof 
mailutils 
msmtp 
nodejs 
procps 
vim 
zip 
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && pecl install 
imagick 
redis 
ssh2-1.3.1 
xdebug 
&& pecl clear-cache 
&& rm -rf /tmp/pear

RUN docker-php-ext-configure 
gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp 
&& docker-php-ext-install 
bcmath 
bz2 
calendar 
exif 
gd 
gettext 
intl 
mbstring 
mysqli 
opcache 
pcntl 
pdo_mysql 
soap 
sockets 
sodium 
sysvmsg 
sysvsem 
sysvshm 
xsl 
zip 
&& docker-php-ext-enable 
imagick 
redis 
ssh2 
xdebug

RUN docker-php-ext-enable apcu

RUN echo "memory_limit=1G" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-memory-limit-php.ini
RUN echo "apc.enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-apcu.ini
RUN echo "apc.enable_cli=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-apcu.ini
RUN echo "opcache.memory_consumption=512MB" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf
RUN echo "opcache.max_accelerated_files=60000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf
RUN echo "opcache.consistency_checks=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf
RUN echo "opcache.validate_timestamps=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf
RUN echo "opcache.enable_cli=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zz-opcache.conf

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/{body,fastcgi} && 
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx

RUN touch /run/nginx.pid && 
chown www-data:www-data /run/nginx.pid

COPY etc/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
COPY etc/nginx /etc/nginx

RUN curl https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar -o /usr/local/bin/magerun 
&& chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/magerun

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor 
&& chown www-data:www-data /var/log/supervisor

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ARG COMPOSER_AUTH

COPY --from=composer:2.6.5@sha256:fb3c5a283f2dc08e08841048498e8a82c3864648c84255b5ad7243b38d33a8db /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN   composer config -g http-basic.repo.magento.com $MAGENTO_PUBLIC_KEY $MAGENTO_PRIVATE_KEY; 
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-enterprise-edition:${MAGENTO_VERSION} .

COPY  bin bin
COPY bin/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint

RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/var/cache
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/var/page_cache
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/var/session